# Can I add a variable within a binding of a TextField within a ForEach loop?

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I am very new to swiftUI and development in general. I am trying to create a dynamic list of TextFields that return strings.

```
    ForEach((1...numberofNAdefects), id: \.self) {
                        
                        TextField("\($0): Enter defect description", text: $nadefect1)
```

The problem i have is that I want the "$nadefect#" return string to increase dynamically with the foreachloop.  Initially my thought would be to add `text: $nadefect\($0)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: That's not possible. But you might be able to store all the bindings you'll use for the text fields in an array and then access them in your ForEach loop by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the string like you suggested is impossible. Nevertheless, implementing a dynamic list of TextFields is quite easy in SwiftUI.

Instead of increasing strings you could use an array of strings:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var defects: [String] = ["", "", ""]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<defects.count, id: \.self) {
            TextField("\($0 + 1): Enter defect description", text: $defects[$0])
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simpler: `ForEach(0..<defects.count, id: \.self)`